# Bind multiple elements values to a single property inside viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i bind multiple control values to a single property inside my viewmodel

**NOT VALID CODE :**

```
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiConverter}">
            <!--Convert From these element-->
            <From ElementName="check1" Path="IsChecked" />
            <From ElementName="check2" Path="IsChecked" />
            <From ElementName="check3" Path="IsChecked" />
            <From ElementName="check4" Path="IsChecked" />
            <!--To Viewmodel Property-->
            <To ElementName="myViewModelProperty" />
        </MultiBinding>

        <CheckBox Name="check1"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="check2"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="check3"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="check4"></CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind on the property as usual

```
<CheckBox Name="check1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty}" />
<CheckBox Name="check2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty}" />
<CheckBox Name="check3" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty}" />
<CheckBox Name="check4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty}" />
```

Then, in the ViewModel :

```
    public Boolean myViewModelProperty
    {
        get {  ...       }

        set {  ...       }
    }
```

Also in the ViewModel, when needed :

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged<Boolean>(() => this.myViewModelProperty);
```

You can bind as many elements values on one property if you want (even if I don't understand 4 checkbox with same property ^^)

MultiBinding is use to bind ONE element value to MANY ViewModel properties.

**Edit** : Considering the fact that 4 checkbox must be converted into a enum :

```
<CheckBox Name="check1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty1}" />
<CheckBox Name="check2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty2}" />
<CheckBox Name="check3" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty3}" />
<CheckBox Name="check4" IsChecked="{Binding Path=myViewModelProperty4}" />


    public Boolean myViewModelProperty1
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.b1;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.b1  =value;
            this.EvaluateMyEnum();
        }
    }

    public Boolean myViewModelProperty2
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.b2;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.b2  =value;
            this.EvaluateMyEnum();
        }
    }

    public Boolean myViewModelProperty3
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.b2;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.b2  =value;
            this.EvaluateMyEnum();
        }
    }

    public Boolean myViewModelProperty4
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.b4;  
        }
        set 
        { 
            this.b4  =value;
            this.EvaluateMyEnum();
        }
    }

    void EvaluateMyEnum()
    {
        this.MyViewModelEnum = ......;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged<MyEnum>(() => this.myViewModelEnum);
    }
```

Comment: I know, but i need to convert these bool to an enum. I can do these but not on a casual way.

Comment: what you need is bind each element value on a property of the view model. So 4 checkbox bind on 4 Boolean in VM. Then, in the ViewModel, do the process to convert the 4 Boolean into the expected enum.

Comment: I've made it like these before. I was hoping for a cleaner way. Thanks anyway.